# GnuCash How to track a bill in A/P and in an asset account and get tracked to customer who reimburses

Tags: gnucash, billing

I incur expenses on behalf of clients who will reimburse.
In quickbooks i would create bill to vendor and track to customer.  expense went to A/P and the the other entry was an asset account.  This was because it was essentially a loan to the customer.  I need to track this to customer report.
When I enter the Bill in gnucash it then asks me to post an invoice.  Is something amiss?  I create a bill, fill in the customer in default chargeback field.  I stipulate the asset account.  It says "post invoice"  and a window pops up with the only account available in the pull down is Accounts receivable.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and have found that creating a "Customer Expense" parent account solves the problem.

I provide o365 for several people on my plan and I want them to reimburse me.

I create Expenses/Customer Expense/User1 and so on...

Bill is from Microsoft (5 X 29.11) and has five line items:

- O365-monthly E3 / expenses/customer expense/user1
- O365-monthly E3 / expenses/customer expense/user2
- O365-monthly E3 / expenses/customer expense/user3
- O365-monthly E3 / expenses/customer expense/user4
- O365-monthly E3 / expenses/customer expense/user5

I do NOT expenses these to my expenses/household/online-services/o365 account because I will be REBILLING; it is NOT my expense - it is just a loan.

Later I Invoice each user for their accumulated items and charge this BACK to the same account.

Come billing time, I just review the list of customers with non-zero balances and invoice them.

Hope this helps.  It works great for my needs.